# Why is it so important to determine whether a friend declaration is the first in its namespace?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[namespace.memdef]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3) (emphases are mine):

> **If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template<sup>106</sup> the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace**. The friend declaration does not
>   by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (6.4.1) or
>   qualified lookup (6.4.3). [ Note: The name of the friend will be
>   visible in its namespace if a matching declaration is provided at
>   namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting
>   friendship). —end note ] If a friend function or function template is
>   called, its name may be found by the name lookup that considers
>   functions from namespaces and classes associated with the types of the
>   function arguments (6.4.2). **If the name in a friend declaration is
>   neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration is a function
>   or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine whether the
>   entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes
>   outside the innermost enclosing namespace**. [ Note: The other forms of
>   friend declarations cannot declare a new member of the innermost
>   enclosing namespace and thus follow the usual lookup rules. —end note
>   ] [ Example: ...

The [code below](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c48875dbde1a0e61) executes correctly irrespective of the fact whether the friend declaration is or is not the first declaration in its namespace.

```
#include<iostream>

namespace N{
    struct A;
    void f(A&);         // If you comment out this declaration, i.e., if the
                        // friend declaration turns out to be the first
                        // declaration in namespace N, the code will still
                        // execute correctly, i.e., printing the same result
                        // below.

    struct A {
        friend void f(A& ra) { std::cout << "friend void f(A&)\n" << ra.i; }
    private:
        int i = 100;
    };
}

N::A a;
int main(){
    f(a);
}
```

This snippet prints out the following:

```
friend void f(A&)
100
```

Answer (score 2):

It is found with [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) because you pass a single parameter from namespace `N`. Example can be changed to this:

```
namespace N{
    void f(int); // If you comment out this declaration, i.e., if the
                 // friend declaration turns out to be the first
                 // declaration in namespace N, the code will fail to compile.

    struct A {
        friend void f(int) { std::cout << "friend void f()\n"; }
        private:
        int i = 100;
    };
}

int main(){
    N::f(1);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KVjKr7CDwkijIdPE)

Comment: But what does that have to do with [namespace.memdef]/3?

Comment: @Alexander `friend void f(int)` declaration alone does not make `f` visible in `N` namespace, just as that quoted snippet says.

Comment: According to my second emphasis in [namespace.memdef]/3 the compiler **does a lookup** to verify whether the name `f` has been previously declared. What is the purpose for this lookup? How does the compiler use this information?

Comment: @Alexander For example to check that friend declaration matches previous declaration, if any. If the first declaration In this code snippet returned `int` instead of `void` then `friend void f(int)` declaration would cause an error.